# MappingSolrConverter doesn't convert dynamicField types when using wildcards

Tags: java, solr, configuration

**schema.xml**

```
<dynamicField name="*_str" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"     
       required="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Document Object:

```
@SolrDocument
  public class Entity{
  @Field("*_str")
  private Map<String, String> identifiers;
```

SolrConfiguration as Java Class:

```
@Configuration
  public Class SolrConfiguration{
  @Bean
    public CustomSolrTemplate solrTemplate() throws Exception {
        SolrServer solrServer = solrServerFactoryBean().getObject();
        CustomSolrTemplate customSolrTemplate = new 
    CustomSolrTemplate(solrServer);
        customSolrTemplate.setSolrConverter(mappingSolrConverter());
        return customSolrTemplate;
    }

  @Bean
    public HttpSolrServerFactoryBean solrServerFactoryBean() {
        HttpSolrServerFactoryBean factory = new HttpSolrServerFactoryBean();
        factory.setUrl(solrServerUrl);
        return factory;
    }

  @Bean
   public SolrConverter mappingSolrConverter(){
        return new MappingSolrConverter(new SimpleSolrMappingContext());
    }
  ...
}
```

Still the @Field identifiers is not get instantiated when reading a **solr.xml**.

What am I doing wrong here?